# How to work around findIndex returning 0 when values are undefined?

Tags: javascript

Ran into this for the first time today.

```js
const needle = {key1: 'value1'}
const haystack = [{key1: 'value1'}, {key2: 'value2'}]

const idx1 = haystack.findIndex((hay) => hay.key1 === needle.key1);
const idx2 = haystack.findIndex((hay) => hay.key2 === needle.key1);
const idx3 = haystack.findIndex((hay) => hay.id === needle.id);
const idx4 = haystack.findIndex((hay) => undefined === undefined);

console.log(idx1, idx2, idx3, idx4)
// 0 -1 0 0

// ideally would return
// 0 -1 -1 0
```

Is there a clever way to get findIndex to return `-1` in this case or do I have to put guards around it?

Comment: Check if the property exists in the needle first before looking through the array? Otherwise comparisons against `undefined` could well turn up many false positives

Comment: Yeah, that's the only thing I can think of but for some reason it seems like it should be unnecessary. I guess I just don't like how `findIndex` works. 

Comment: It makes the most intuitive sense to me... don't perform a search before checking that the values you're searching for are reasonable. Same logic would apply to `.find`, `.filter`...

Comment: How about `const keyName = "key1"; haystack.findIndex(hay => (keyName in hay && keyName in needle) ? hay[keyName] === needle[keyName] : false)`?

Comment: The title doesn't make sense. `hay` and `needle`aren't `undefined`.

Comment: @code just `hay => keyName in hay && keyName in needle && hay[keyName] === needle[keyName]`

Comment: about add condition check   : `const idx3 = haystack.findIndex((hay) => hay.id === needle.id & hay.id);`

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Thanks @Xupitan. I like your solution.</sup>

```js
const idx = haystack.findIndex((hay) => hay.id && hay.id === needle.id);

console.log(idx)
// -1
```